# Persist RxJava calls between activities using Dagger2

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have a `BehaviorRelay` object in `ExecutionStream` class which handles network calls. Please refer to `ExecutionStream` class.

I can call `requestTrackingAndExecution()` method from any activity. I have implemented Dagger2 dependency such that I can inject `ExecutionStream` instance in any activity.

My dagger2 configuration:

```
@PerApplication
@Provides
public ExecutionStream provideExecutionStream(PmsApi pmsApi) {
    return new ExecutionStream(pmsApi);
}
```

`@PerApplication` annotation

```
@Scope
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface PerApplication { }
```

WHAT I NEED TO DO:
I want to call `requestTrackingAndExecution()` method from Activity A and subscribe to its emitted data in Activity B.

Currently, suubscriber in Activity B is not getting any data emitted from activity A<--- SEE HERE

I have injected ExecutionStream class in both activities like `@Inject ExecutionStream executionStream;`

For emitting observable, I am calling `internshipAndTrackingRelay.accept(data);` in `requestTrackingAndExecution()` method after getting data from a network call.

Code for subscribing to relay:

```
executionStream.internshipAndTracking()
                    .subscribe(
                            new Consumer<ExecutionStream.InternshipAndTrackingContainer>() {
                                @Override
                                public void accept(ResponseData data){
                                      //do some stuff with responsedata
                                }
                            });
```

My `ExecutionStream` class:

```
public class ExecutionStream {

@NonNull private PmsApi pmsApi;
@NonNull private final BehaviorRelay<InternExecutionContainer> internExecutionRelay = BehaviorRelay.create();
@NonNull private final BehaviorRelay<InternshipAndTrackingContainer> internshipAndTrackingRelay = BehaviorRelay.create();

public ExecutionStream(@NonNull PmsApi pmsApi) {
    this.pmsApi = pmsApi;
}

@NonNull
public Observable<InternshipAndTrackingContainer> internshipAndTracking() {
    return internshipAndTrackingRelay.hide();
}

public void requestTrackingAndExecution(String internshipExecutionId, String internExecutionId) {
                   // Do some network call
                   // Get response
                   internshipAndTrackingRelay.accept(new InternshipAndTrackingContainer(responseData));

                    }
                });
    }

/**
 * This function returns combined response of both apis
 * This returns when both apis are finished calling
 * @return Observable response
 */
private BiFunction<
        InternshipExecutionResponse,
        TrackingDataResponse,
        TrackingAndExecution>
getMergingBiFuntionForTrackingAndExecution() {
    return new BiFunction<InternshipExecutionResponse, TrackingDataResponse, TrackingAndExecution>() {
        @Override
        public TrackingAndExecution apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull InternshipExecutionResponse internshipExecutionResponse, @io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull TrackingDataResponse trackingDataResponse) throws Exception {
            return new TrackingAndExecution(internshipExecutionResponse,trackingDataResponse);
        }
    };
}

public class InternshipAndTrackingContainer {

    public boolean isError;
    public boolean isEmpty;
    public TrackingAndExecution trackingAndExecution;

    public InternshipAndTrackingContainer() {
        this.isError = true;
        this.trackingAndExecution = null;
        this.isEmpty = false;
    }

    public InternshipAndTrackingContainer(TrackingAndExecution trackingAndExecution) {
        this.trackingAndExecution = trackingAndExecution;
        this.isError = false;
        this.isEmpty = false;
    }

    public InternshipAndTrackingContainer(boolean isEmpty) {
        this.trackingAndExecution = null;
        this.isError = false;
        this.isEmpty = isEmpty;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

I was reinitializing my ApplicationModule again and again.

Changed this:

```
public ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
    ApplicationComponent component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .networkModule(new NetworkModule())
                .ApplicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .build();

    return component;
}
```

To this:

```
public synchronized ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
        if(component == null) {
            component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                    .networkModule(new NetworkModule())
                    .ApplicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                    .build();
        }
        return component;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does Activity B subscribe to the `internshipAndTrackingRelay` before Activity A runs the `requestTrackingAndExecution()` method?

Comment: No. Activity B comes after Activity A

Comment: Does Activity A receive any data?  Can you post a log of your network calls?  Are you sure you are receiving a response from both the tracking and execution calls?

Comment: I found a solution. Please see the answer. I defined singletons but I was recreating component each time.